# How to run Android app remotely from GitHub?

Tags: java, android, git, github, version-control

Let's say there is a public repository of Android project in GitHub. I would like to ask, if there is any fast way to directly "checkout" that repository, automatically compile source code of latest commit and run as Android application?

There is any fast or "modern" way to do this? Or firstly I should clone that repository to my local pc, import it in Android Studio, etc, etc.. and run?

Sorry for maybe lame question but I am just a beginner of using source control systems and especially GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using Android Studio:

- Close all open projects.
- You should be at the quickstart menu for Android Studio now. Select "Check out project from Version Control"
- Enter the github URL for the repository you want to clone and choose the directory
- Give a name for the Project / Directory name (probably same as the project you want to clone!)

You could just click VCS at the top bar when you are in an open project, and import project from that menu, but it's probably best you close all projects already open.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is continuous integration. Have a look at some continuous integration technologies:

1. [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)
2. [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/android)
3. [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)